Comparing cell values in files with identical names
I have a process that exports two sets of identical Excel files - a first set where users can edit data and a second reference set that enables file compare to identify edits made in the first set. Each file has only one sheet and the file name is the sheet name plus _YYYYMMDD and extension (14 characters).
I need a macro to loop through both sets of files and highlight the edits in each edited file's only sheet. The sheet number is different in each pair of files, so I need to use the sheet name, not the sheet number.
My macro runs, but applies the interior color to every cell, not just the edited cells. I presume this is due to not being able to have two files with identical filenames open simultaneously. Help to fix this problem greatly appreciated.
    Sub Compare_Spreadsheets_DoWhile_20240703_1()
    Dim editPath, refPath, filename, refFname, editFname, refFile, editwsname, refwsname As String
    Dim editwbk, refwbk As Workbook
    Dim editws, refws As Worksheet
    Dim editFile As File
    Dim wbk, FileSystem, Folder, FSO, editFolder, Fls As Object
    Dim i, j As Integer

    editPath = "C:\xxxx\edit_test\"
    refPath = "C:\xxxx\ref_test\"

    refFile = Dir(refPath & "*.xls*")
    
Do While refFile <> ""
    
    Set refwbk = ActiveWorkbook
    refFname = refwbk.Name

    'Remove _YYYYMMDD.xlsx (14 characters) from filename to get sheetname
    refwsname = Left(refwbk.Name, Len(refwbk.Name) - 14)
    Set refws = refwbk.Sheets(refwsname)
    
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set editFolder = FileSystem.GetFolder(editPath)
    
    For Each editFile In editFolder.Files
        filename = editFile.Name
        
        'Check if edited file name equals reference file name
        If StrComp(filename, refFname, 0) Then

            Set editwbk = Workbooks.Open(editPath & filename)
            editFname = editwbk.Name

            'Remove _YYYYMMDD.xlsx (14 characters) from filename to get sheetname
            editwsname = Left(editwbk.Name, Len(editwbk.Name) - 14)
            Set editws = editwbk.Sheets(editwsname)
            
            'Compare each cell in the edited sheet with the reference sheet
                For Each cell In editws.UsedRange
                    If cell.Value <> refws.Range(cell.Address).Value Then
                        cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                        'MsgBox "Changed value in " & cell.Address & " in sheet " & editws.Name
                    End If
                Next cell
            editwbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
            
        End If
    Next editFile

refFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub


What do you mean by "the edits in each edited file"? To highlight the cells which are different in compared sheets?

Yes. To highlight the cells which are different. The pairs of files are created with identical cell values and I want to be able to immediately identify edited values by yellow highlighted cells

What do you expect from the line Set refwbk = ActiveWorkbook? Should it be the active workbook when start running the code? If so, why setting it in a loop, as many times as many files are returned from refPath? Do you think that the active workbook will be the one having refFile name? If so, such an understanding is wrong. You cade needs to open it. If not, please better explain what you try doing... Then, coloring the cells one at a time shows down the code speed.

Yes, thanks - my intention was that ActiveWorkbook has the refFile name. I understood that the Do While would open it. The loop is intended to open Myfilename1.xlsx in the ref folder and then find Myfilename1.xlsx in the edit folder and compare the Myfilename1 sheets. Then proceed to Myfilename2.xlsx in the ref folder, etc.

BTW I need Set refwbk = ActiveWorkbook so that I can get the filename to use for both the If StrComp... Then condition and the sheetname. Perhaps there is a smarter way to do that....

No availability right now, but I will try adapting your code. Basically there are some issues. strComp is wrongly used, no any error handling if there are some other files type, if their name is less than 14 characters a error will be raised, the modified workbook is not closed and so on...

OK, I will try now adapting the code to work as (I understood) it should...

Please, test the updated code I supplied and send some feedback.

Please, test the next adapted code:
Sub Compare_Spreadsheets_DoWhile_20240703_1()
    Dim editPath As String, refPath As String, filename As String, refFname As String
    Dim editFname As String, refFile As String, editwsname As String, refwsname As String
    Dim editwbk As Workbook, refwbk As Workbook
    Dim editws As Worksheet, refws As Worksheet, cel As Range, URng As Range, countP As Long
    Dim editFile As Object, FileSystem As Object, editFolder As Object

    editPath = "C:\Teste VBA Excel\TestCSV\" ' "C:\xxxx\edit_test\"
    refPath = "C:\Teste VBA Excel\testDatBis\" ' "C:\xxxx\ref_test\"

    refFile = Dir(refPath & "*.xls*")
    
 Do While refFile <> ""
    
    Set refwbk = Workbooks.Open(refPath & refFile) 'open the necessary workbook!
    refFname = refwbk.name

    'Remove _YYYYMMDD.xlsx (14 characters) from filename to get the workbook base name
    refwsname = left(refwbk.name, Len(refwbk.name) - 14)
    Set refws = refwbk.Sheets(1) 'the sheet name does not matter (being only one...)
    
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set editFolder = FileSystem.GetFolder(editPath)
    
    Dim strExt As String
    For Each editFile In editFolder.files
        filename = editFile.name
        
        strExt = FileSystem.GetExtensionName(editFile) 'extract the file extension
        If Len(filename) > 15 And strExt Like "xls*" Then 'process only files having their name longger than 15 characters
                                                          'and extension looking as xls*
            'Remove _YYYYMMDD.xlsx (14 characters) from filename to get the name reference:
            editwsname = left(filename, Len(filename) - 14)
            If editwsname = refwsname Then
                Set editwbk = Workbooks.Open(editPath & filename)
                Set editws = editwbk.Sheets(1)
                
                countP = countP + 1 'count the pair of compared workbooks
                
                'Compare each cell in the edited sheet with the reference sheet
                For Each cel In editws.UsedRange
                    If cel.Value <> refws.Range(cel.address).Value Then
                        addToRange URng, cel 'place the cell in a Union range
                    End If
                Next cel
                'color the union range at once (if diffrences have been found):
                If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.Interior.Color = vbYellow 'color all the cells at once
                
                Set URng = Nothing 'reinitialize the variable for the next iteration
                editwbk.Close SaveChanges:=True 'close the edited workbook and save it
            End If
         End If
            
    Next editFile
    refwbk.Close False 'close the reference workbook, too
    refFile = Dir
 Loop
 
 MsgBox "Ready..." & vbCrLf & _
        "(Compared " & countP & " pair(s) of files...)", vbInformation, "Job Done"
End Sub

Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub

After testing it and considering that it does what it should do, you can add some optimization (ScreenUpdating, Calculation) to skip updating the screen and calculating formulas (in all open workbooks), making the code a little faster...

Many thanks @FaneDuru - some comments: Unfortunately the problem with two files with same the file name still disrupts - I will work on adding a prefix to the reference file name.
addToRange gives a Sub or Function not defined error - I do not know addToRange, but will work on this.
I cannot use Sheets(1) as the sheet number is not 1 - the files are generated from a file with multiple sheets, so each exported workbook has a single sheet but with a different sheet number.

@cdfj Ups... I forgot posting the Sub. I will do it now. Please, test the updated solution. In fact, copy only the Sub I posted at the code part end... It shouldn't need something else if the workbook naming respects the rule you described...

@cdfj if not something confidential, can you share two such workbooks to be compared? I tested the above code on two such workbooks and it worked as it should...

That is very kind. I can make some with test data tomorrow. There is still something wrong with the looping in my tests.

@cdfj What do you mean by "something wrong with the looping"? Is there any raised error? Does it work without error but it does not do anything in terms of highlighting? Or, what?

Many thanks for your help @FaneDuru - now solved by removing the For Each loop

With many thanks for @FaneDuru for his help. I have realized that the For Each loop is unnecessary as the edit file can be opened directly in the Do While loop by deriving the edit file name from the reference file name (which now has a 4 character prefix to avoid attempting to simultaneously open two files with identical names).
    Sub Compare_Spreadsheet_Pairs()
'Paired files in two separate folders
'Reference files have Ref_ prefix in file name
'Sheet names identical in each pair and are file name minus _YYYYYMMDD.xlsx

Dim editPath As String, refPath As String, refFname As String, editFl As String, editFname As String, refFile As String, editwsname As String, refwsname1 As String, refwsname As String
Dim editwbk As Workbook, refwbk As Workbook
Dim editws As Worksheet, refws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range, URng As Range
Dim countP As Long
Dim editFile  As Object, FileSystem As Object, editFolder As Object

    editPath = "C:\xxxx\edit_test\"
    refPath = "C:\xxxx\ref_test\"

    refFile = Dir(refPath & "*.xls*")
    
 Do While refFile <> ""
    
    Set refwbk = Workbooks.Open(refPath & refFile)
    refFname = refwbk.Name

    'Remove _YYYYMMDD.xlsx (14 characters) from filename to get the workbook base name
    refwsname1 = Left(refwbk.Name, Len(refwbk.Name) - 14)
    'Remove Ref_ (4 characters) from base name to get sheetname
    refwsname = Right(refwsname1, Len(refwsname1) - 4)

    Set refws = refwbk.Worksheets(refwsname)
    
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set editFolder = FileSystem.GetFolder(editPath)
    
    editFl = Right(refwbk.Name, Len(refwbk.Name) - 4)

        Set editwbk = Workbooks.Open(editPath & editFl)
        editFname = editwbk.Name
        
        'Remove _YYYYMMDD.xlsx (14 characters) from filename to get sheetname
        editwsname = Left(editwbk.Name, Len(editwbk.Name) - 14)
        
        Set editws = editwbk.Worksheets(editwsname)
            
            countP = countP + 1 'count the pair of compared workbooks
            
            'Compare each cell in edited sheet with reference sheet
            For Each cell In editws.UsedRange
                If cell.Value <> refws.Range(cell.Address).Value Then
                    'cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    addToRange URng, cell 'place the cell in a Union range
                End If
            Next cell
            If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Set URng = Nothing
            
            editwbk.Close SaveChanges:=True

    refwbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
    refFile = Dir
 
 Loop
 
 MsgBox countP & " pair(s) of files compared", vbInformation, "Job done"
End Sub

Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub


I cannot get you, I am afraid... Is it something wrong in the code I posted? What For Each loop has been removed? My code is also able to deal with the case of some other file existing in the examined folder (having names less than 14 digits, different types than Excel etc.). Anyhow, your variable declarations are wrong... Declaring Dim editwbk, refwbk As Workbook correctly declares only the second variable. The first one is Variant. And the same for all declaration lines. Didn't you look to my code trying to understand what I did? Do you think I played with declarations?

Thank you for pointing out my error. I was not aware the declarations defaulted to Variant that way. Regarding For Each - it is not needed in my use case as all the files to be compared are pairs and the name of the edited paired file can be derived from the paired reference file. My apologies if I have upset you - it is due to my lack of knowledge and I am very grateful for your time and help.

But you did not mention in your question that the reference file does not have the 14 digits extension! On contrarious, your code builds the workbook name removing that 14 digits suffix... How could anybody understand something you never told?

Both files in the pair have the 14 character suffix and I believe I made that clear. I subsequently added the Ref_ prefix to the reference file to enable both files to be open simultaneously. Removing the 14 character suffix and the Ref_ prefix provides the sheet name. I believe I also made that clear,

Then, how Set editwbk = Workbooks.Open(editPath & editFl) can work if you defined editFl by removing its first 4 characters? Do the workbooks have the same name including that part you try removing to obtain the sheet name? And only the first four starting characters are different in their full path names? Removing these characters for nothing... You can use (as I used) Set editws = editwbk.Worksheets(1). Since, only a sheet exists. Never mind, it looks that we are speaking two different languages, not referring to English, no offence... I wish you a good day!

The idea is to compare Ref_Myfile1_YYYYMMDD.xlsx (the open file) with Myfile1_YYYYMMDD.xlsx. The editFl string removes Ref_, so editFl provides the name of the second file to be opened as Myfile1_YYYYMMDD.xlsx. Which is why the For Each is not needed.

If so, Myfile1_YYYYMMDD.xlsx must be its full name (path included. Should I understand that its full name differs by only first 4 characters? I cannot imagine such a scenario, even if it is a sub folder. But probably I spent too much time to clarify this question and I am not so logic, anymore. Have a nice day! In fact, can you show exactly the two full names in discussion? To close the issue in an elegant way...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I am drving....
